# Recursividade: Calcular a soma dos primeiros valores ímpares positivos começando em 5

Tags: java, lógica, recursão

Estou fazendo alguns exercícios sobre e parei nesse faz uns dias.

**Cheguei até o seguinte código:**

```
  /**
    * Funcao: Soma dos primeiros valores ímpares positivos começando em 5.
    * @param quantidade - quantidade de valores a somar
    *
    * valores esperados para quantidade = 1
    * 5
    * valores esperados para quantidade = 4
    * 32
    */
  public static int funcao06 (int quantidade){

    int resposta = 5;

    if(quantidade > 1){

      IO.println ("(" + quantidade + ") Valor Impar: " + (funcao06(quantidade - 1) + 2));      

    } else {

      resposta = 5;
      IO.println ("(" + quantidade + ") Valor Impar: " + resposta);

    }// fim do se

    return (resposta);

  } // fim do funcao06
```

**A saída da minha função:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que estou fazendo de errado ?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu consegui a solução seguindo o seguinte raciocínio:

- Todo número ímpar é gerado pela fórmula 2*n + 1;
- O caso base da recursão é f(0) = 5 (deve começar de 5);

Com essas hipóteses tentamos generalizar uma fórmula para a recursão:

```
f(0) = 5
f(1) = 5 + 7 = 12              = f(0) + 7
f(2) = 5 + 7 + 9 = 21          = f(1) + 9
f(3) = 5 + 7 + 9 + 11 = 32     = f(2) + 11
```

Pela tabela acima percebemos que acrescentamos um valor ao resultado da função anterior. Esse valor pode ser alcançado com a fórmula `2 * (n + 2) + 1` o mais 2 na fórmula dos números ímpares é por conta do início no 5.

Logo a fórmula final fica:

f(n) = f(n-1) + 2 * (n+2) + 1;

Transformando em código temos:

```
public int soma(int quantidade) {
    if(quantidade == 0) {
        return 5;
    } else {
        return soma(quantidade - 1) + 2*(quantidade + 2) + 1 ;
    }
}
```

Veja no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/0vmZ5k)

Comment: Observei que nesse caso quando eu quiser a soma dos três primeiros números eu teria que chamar a função no main da seguinte maneira: soma (quantidade - 1); 
Pois f(0) = 5 é a primeira parcela da soma!

Comment: É questão de gosto, você pode alterar a função para começar a contar a partir do 1 (ao invés do 0) modificando o caso base para quantidade == 1, mas normalmente na programação começamos a contar do 0.

Comment: Sim, deixei o comentário como uma observação mesmo! =)

Answer (score 2):

Solução recursiva para somar uma dada quantidade de números impares a partir de um valor inicial:

```
private static int somarImpares(int valor, int quantidade) {
    assert valor % 2 != 0 : "valor: " + valor;
    assert quantidade > 0 : quantidade;

    if (quantidade > 1)
        return valor + somarImpares(valor+2,  quantidade-1);
    else
        return valor;
}
```

<sup>(funciona tambem para números pares se o primeiro `assert` for removido, os dois `assert` são principalmente para documentação)</sup>

Para *facilitar*, o seguinte método também pode ser implementado

```
 public static int somarImparesAPartir5(int quantidade) {
    return somarImpares(5, quantidade);
}
```